# Is there detailed information about kotlinx.browser?

Tags: kotlin, browser

I'm making Automated Zoom Opener for Zoom online class.
But, I don't know how to open website with Kotlin/Native on Windows PC.
So I searched for Kotlin module which is similar to webbrowser module in python.
I found a module, kotlinx.browser, but I couldn't find any information about it.
Can you find or provide some information and sample code about it?
(Or other ways to open website with Kotlin/Native on Windows PC.)

Answer (score 1):

The package `kotlinx.browser` is part of `kotlin-stdlib`. According to [(1)](https://docs.w3cub.com/kotlin/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlinx.browser/index) it needs Kotlin/JS as prerequisite. See [(2)](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-project-setup.html) how to set up Kotlin/JS. A small example on the usage of `kotlin.browser` can be found at [(3)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/hands-on/Building%20Web%20Applications%20with%20React%20and%20Kotlin%20JS/08_Using_an_External_REST_API).